# How to pass primarykey to the put_item in DynamoDB for nested JSON

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to use `put_item(Item = data)` to insert a json object into DynamoDB.

Is it possible if we have the primary key field nested in the json. Like below example.

```
{
    "data": {
        "Details": {
            "Number": "123456"

        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key Number in the item
```

I couldn't find any reference if we can pass the primaryfield as some argument in boto3.

Answer (score 0):

"Number" isn't a data type, but "N" is.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item

Comment: Number here is the json field not related to any data type. It is the primary key for the dynamo DB table

Comment: Ok. You can't have an object as a key. And if you were setting a nested attribute you would need to specify the data type.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The only data types allowed for primary key attributes are string, number, or binary.

So no, it is not possible to have a nested primary key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html

Comment: Thanks! that's what I needed confirmation for. I have already extracted the Primary key from the nested json and updated at the top level. It is working as expected.